# Excel sheet index search and merge column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a two Microsoft excel sheet file1 and file2.

file1 contain following CPU info.

```
hostname  | CPULoad
_________________________
server1   |   10%
server10  |   3%
server25  |   37%
```

file2 contain Memory Usage info.

```
hostname   | Memory Usage
_________________________
server12   |   8GB
server25   |   2GB
server10   |   999MB
```

I want to merge this sheet in single sheet so it search Host name from file1 and pull out Memory usage data from file2 and merge them in single file. I know we can do in Excel but I don't know how?

Comment: Your sample data has servers on both sides that are not present in the other table. Is that the case in real life? If it is, what do you want to do with these line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use VLOOKUP like this:

=VLOOKUP(first cell on destination sheet, range on second sheet including both columns, number of the memory usage column, 0)

Drag this formula down and you will get all your memory usages.